# Using number theory to solve $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to find all solutions to $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$. I understand that there are various ways of solving it, such as looking at the Cayley table for $U(\mathbb{Z}_{19})$, the multiplicative group of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ that are relatively prime to 19. The table shows that there are two elements of order 3, which are 7 and 11; but I'm interested to learn how this can be classified and solved through number theory techniques. I would appreciate your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$19|(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Clearly, $x\equiv1\pmod{19}$ is a solution

Again, $x^2+x+1\equiv0\iff(2x+1)^2\equiv-3\equiv16\equiv4^2$

$\iff[(2x+1)-4][(2x+1)+4]\equiv0$

If $2x+1\equiv4\pmod{19},2x\equiv3\equiv22\iff x\equiv11$

Comment: ...and if $2x+1\equiv -4\pmod {19}$, then $2x\equiv 14\pmod {19}\iff x\equiv 7\pmod {19}$.

Comment: Would the same method be used to solve x^11 ≡ 1 mod 23?

Comment: @user975, I think, that'd be cumbersome. Discrete logarithm can be a better option which needs a primitive root

Comment: I don't have discrete logarithms in my notes but could Fermats Little Theorem be used here?

Comment: @user975 In the case of $x^{11}\equiv1\pmod{23}$ you can use the fact that the group of invertible elements modulo $23$ has $22$ elements. So $x^{11}\equiv1$ for half of the elements.